# RightFax COM DLL - Successful Fax Transmission

Tags: rightfax

I am using the RightFax COM DLL that seems to be working, but I need to know if a fax transmission was successful.

Is there a property that can be set that will email the user of a successful fax transmission?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the person to get a notification via email - I would just set their account in Enterprise Fax Manager to get the email notifications.  That would be easiest and wouldn't require any development effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a windows service that keep checking a list of faxes using their Handle id.
After sending the fax, the value of handle would be filled (objFax.Handle). < it is empty before fax sending>.

The windows service would periodically check the status of fax status. You can look for your fax using the handle value. The faxes can be repented as XML, objUser.Folders["Main"].Faxes.XML .

Using LINQ or any other XML parsing code, search for you  fax via the handle, and look for the "FaxStatusEx" attribute value. 6 is Done Sending.

List of satus values :
        fsUnborn = 0,
        fsNeedsFCS = 1,
        fsNeedsConversion = 2,
        fsNeedsToBeSent = 3,
        fsInConversion = 4,
        fsInSend = 5,
        fsDoneOK = 6,
        fsManualFCS = 7,
        fsInSchedule = 8,
        fsDoneError = 9,
        fsDuplicate = 10,
        fsError = 11,
        fsNeedsAttention = 12,
        fsNeedsAttachment = 13,
        fsHeldForPreview = 14,
        fsInOCR = 15,
        fsInPrint = 16,
        fsQueuedForPrinting = 17,
        fsQueuedForOCR = 18,
        fsInValidation = 19,
        fsInApproval = 20,